# Getting a 403 Error with valid API key - Private App

Tags: rest, shopify

I've created a Private App (got the API Key, Password, and Secret) but it's not allowing me access for some reason. I'm issuing the GET request without any parameters... should I be using something in the request?  Thanks! Josh

```
{"response":
  "Error message:
    GET
    https://58b135637023de04edb493880e25XXXX:2d6982192cdc0ea753ba6a729c9dXXXX@ellabing-com.myshopify.com/admin/products.json? returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized

  "Server response": {
      "errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"
  },
  "remoteServiceStatus":1,
  "success":false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm… can you check the request that’s coming from your machine using a web debugging proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](https://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see if an Authorization header is really being passed in the request?

The format that `https://58b135637023de04edb493880e25XXXX:2d6982192cdc0ea753ba6a729c9dXXXX@ellabing-com.myshopify.com/admin/products.json` is in works for browsers and some clients, but is an unofficial shorthand, and not always supported.